# Primefaces datatable column update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a Primefaces datatable and what I want to do is after user clicks to  "removeItemsFromList" button, program will update datatable records. Datatable is updating but my checkbox column doesn't. After I click to button, records are updating but selected checkboxes still remains selected. I want them to reset. I mean I want all datatable to reset.Is there any easy way to do this?

My commandbutton;

```
<p:commandButton value="removeItemsFromList"
                         actionListener="#{myController.sendToArchive()}"
                         update="myDatatableId"
                         icon="ui-icon-folder-open"/>
```

My datatable column;

```
<p:column headerText="">
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{myController.addToSelectionList(iss)}"/>
                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </p:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality using the resetInput component:

```
<p:commandButton value="removeItemsFromList"
                     actionListener="#{myController.sendToArchive()}"
                     update="myDatatableId"
                     icon="ui-icon-folder-open">
    <p:resetInput target="myDatatableId" /> 
</p:commandButton>
```

For other solutions i can suggest:

A. Javascript / JQuery

B. Binding the value of the checkbox to a bean variable, and set it to false after each update